# Jquery Submit is causing a serious issue while processing the callback function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

I've made program via which I am trying to create grids after taking value for **number of boxes in rows and columns**. When I submit the form by clicking on submit button; I'm unable to view effects as they disappear in seconds.

Now when I handle the same event using **click event handler** I am able to see all my effects. Why **submit event handler** is failing while **click event handler** is becoming a success? What is logic behind **the disappearance of my output in seconds after pressing submit button** whereas on the other hand **the same output is visible for a long time when I am using the** *click event handler*?

**required output is given by below script ->**

```js
    $(()=>{

        function grid(row, col){

            for(let i=1; i<=(row*col); ++i)
                $('.Grid').append($('<div></div>').addClass("Tile"));
        }

        $('button').click(()=>{
        
          $('.Grid').width($('#a').val() * 40); 
          $('.Grid').height($('#b').val() * 40); 

          grid($('#a').val(), $('#b').val());

        });

    });
```

```css
    .Grid{
        font-size: 0px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
    }

    .Tile{
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: grey;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div class="Grid"></div>

        <button>Display!</button>

        <form>
        columns -> <input id="a" type="number"> <br/>
      rows -> <input id="b" type="number"> <br/>
        </form>
```

**momentary(not required) output is given by below script ->**

```js
    $(()=>{

        function grid(row, col){

            for(let i=1; i<=(row*col); ++i)
                $('.Grid').append($('<div></div>').addClass("Tile"));
        }

        $('form').submit(()=>{
        
          $('.Grid').width($('#a').val() * 40); 
          $('.Grid').height($('#b').val() * 40); 

          grid($('#a').val(), $('#b').val());

        });

    });
```

```css
    .Grid{
        font-size: 0px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
    }

    .Tile{
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: grey;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div class="Grid"></div>

        <form>
        columns -> <input id="a" type="number"> <br/>
      rows -> <input id="b" type="number"> <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Submit basically sends data to the server using the URL

Comment: @subeeshk don't know anything about server-clients. so as per you I should avoid this submit and instead stick to click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form, browsers will perform a full page reload as they attempt to "submit" the data, usually to the location specified in the form's `action` attribute. This is 100% expected behaviour.

You can prevent this default behaviour by intercepting the event when the form is submitted. In your code, when you add the `submit` handler, you have access to the underlying `event` and a function called `preventDefault()`.

When you call this, the event is stopped. Here's a more in-depth explanation of how it all works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

And I've updated your code snippet below with a working example:

```js
$(() => {

  function grid(row, col) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= (row * col); ++i)
      $('.Grid').append($('<div></div>').addClass("Tile"));
  }

  $('form').submit((event) => {
    
    event.preventDefault();
    
    $('.Grid').width($('#a').val() * 40);
    $('.Grid').height($('#b').val() * 40);

    grid($('#a').val(), $('#b').val());

  });

});
```

```css
.Grid {
  font-size: 0px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.Tile {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Grid"></div>
<form>
  columns -> <input id="a" type="number" /> <br/> rows -> <input id="b" type="number" /> <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```